# How to make an old school Sprite movement like Pokemon (Tile to Tile)

Tags: xna, sprite, game-physics

I'm making a **Pokemon like** game and I need to make my Sprite move like in Pokemon's games.
I mean, **tile to tile**, cell to cell. I'm using **tIDE** (a tile map editor) and my Tiles width is **32px**. I want the player **moves 32px per 32px** with an animation during the movement. Exactly like in Pokemon. So if I hold a key the player moves continually and if I press a key one time he just moves once so 32px.

Here is my current move function:

```
public void movePlayer(String keyDown, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (keyDown == "up")
        {
            playerPosition.Y -= 2;

            //Animation part, with a timer to switch animation
            if (time > 0)
            {
                directionSprite = directionSpriteTab[4];
                time -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                time2 = interval;
            }
            if (time2 > 0 && time <= 0)
            {
                directionSprite = directionSpriteTab[5];
                time2 -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            }
            if (time2 <= 0 && time <= 0)
            {
                time = interval;
            }
        }
        //same for other keys ...
        }
```

With that code my player moves smoothly but when I stop pressing a key he stops between two Tiles and it's really annoying with the collisions, for example when I want to enter a house, the door is 32px large and it's difficult to make the player enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add boolean variables or an enum to hold the state of the player's movement (an enum is probably better but for simplicity I'll use bool in the example). For example

```
bool movingUp = false; // Set to true when keyDown == "up".
```

Then you can have an if statement checking if the player is at the coordinates of the next tile. If he's not, continue updating playerPosition.Y. Something like this

```
 if (keyDown == "up")
 {
     movingUp = true;
     // Could be type Vector2 or something else, depends on what playerPosition is.
     playerMoveDestination = new Point(playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y - 32);
 }

 if (movingUp)
 {
     // Calculates the distance from the destination tile.
     // When the distance is small enough you want to snap to the tile to avoid 
     // overshooting. In this case the snap distance is less than 2 pixels because the 
     // character moves 2 pixels per frame.
     if (playerPosition.Y - playerMoveDestination.Y < 2)
     {
         playerPosition.Y = playerMoveDestination.Y;
         movingUp = false;
     }
     else
     {
         playerPosition.Y -= 2;

         if (time > 0)
         {
             directionSprite = directionSpriteTab[4];
             time -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
             time2 = interval;
         }
         if (time2 > 0 && time <= 0)
         {
             directionSprite = directionSpriteTab[5];
             time2 -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
         }
         if (time2 <= 0 && time <= 0)
         {
             time = interval;
         }
     }
 }
```

Now if the player lets go of the Up key, it will keep moving the character until it reaches the next tile.

EDIT: Sorry, I have an error in the code. When the player is exactly on a tile, playerPosition.Y % 32 evaluates to 0, which is less than 2, so when the up key is pressed that gets executed right away and it stops moving. To fix this, you could have a playerMoveDestination variable, and when the player presses the Up key it's set to (playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y - 32). I changed the code to do this.

Comment: Changed the answer to fix the error. Please accept the answer if it works for you. We need more games like Pokemon :)

Comment: Ty for your help, I don't think the game gonna be finished ^^" It's just a project for school. I answered you answer there still some problems :P

Answer (score 1):

Now the Sprite moves normally but not Tile to Tile... He moves like before if I release the key he stops and doesn't continue to the direction tile.

And when I add the "down" key part it makes strange movements x)

Here is the code with "down" can you see if I made something wrong ?

```
    public void movePlayer(String keyDown, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (keyDown == "up")
        {
            movingUp = true;
            // Could be type Vector2 or something else, depends on what playerPosition is.
            playerMoveDestination = new Vector2(playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y - 32);
        }

        if (movingUp)
        {
            // Calculates the distance from the destination tile.
            // When the distance is small enough you want to snap to the tile to avoid 
            // overshooting. In this case the snap distance is 2 or less pixels because the 
            // character moves 2 pixels per frame.
            if (playerPosition.Y - playerMoveDestination.Y < 2)
            {
                playerPosition.Y = playerMoveDestination.Y;
                movingUp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                playerPosition.Y -= 2;
            }
        }

        if (keyDown == "down")
        {
            movingDown = true;
            // Could be type Vector2 or something else, depends on what playerPosition is.
            playerMoveDestination = new Vector2(playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y + 32);
        }
        if (movingDown)
        {
            // Calculates the distance from the destination tile.
            // When the distance is small enough you want to snap to the tile to avoid 
            // overshooting. In this case the snap distance is 2 or less pixels because the 
            // character moves 2 pixels per frame.
            if (playerPosition.Y + playerMoveDestination.Y < 2)
            {
                playerPosition.Y = playerMoveDestination.Y;
                movingDown = false;
            }
            else
            {
                playerPosition.Y += 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I initialized the "playerMoveDestination" and the movingDown/Up bool like that:

```
    bool movingUp = false; // Set to true when keyDown == "up".
    bool movingDown = false;

    Vector2 playerMoveDestination;
```

I put them above the "movePlayer" function.

Thanks again for your help !